Combine ggpubr and ggpattern packages
Has someone ever found a way to fill bareplot with stripes in ggbarplot (ggpubr package, one example below), using for example ggpattern package ?
Thanks !
data <- mtcars
data$cars <- rownames(data)

barplot <- ggbarplot(data,
                     x = "cars",
                     y = "qsec", 
                           add = c("mean_sd", "point"),
                     fill = "cars") +
  labs(tag = "A") +
  rremove("legend") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        plot.tag = element_text(size = 20))

